# Count the number of permutations

Tags: graph, dynamic-programming, permutation, combinatorics, directed-graph

Hey I'm taking a DS&A course, and we had an interesting homework question regarding counting permutations. The problem is the following:

There is are *N*(*N* <= 15) people each with an id from 1 to *N*. All N people have a list of numbers they will accept. You have an array of size *N* numbers called *A*. You can permutate *A* however you like. For each permutation, the first number in *A* goes to the first person, the second number goes to the second person, and so on. What is the number of permutations of *A* where, for every person, their assigned number in *A* is also in their list?

I've tried thinking about using directed graphs, but couldn't figure it out. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Interesting question. I think the simplest approach (possibly not the most efficient one) would be to use backtracking. Iterate on the possible numbers to use for person 1. For each used number, iterate on the possible numbers to use for person 2 (those are the numbers accepted for person number 2, minus the number already used for person 1). Etc. If you hit a dead-end (no number left available for someone), discount the partial solution immediately. If you hit a complete solution (everyone got a number) add 1 to the number of permutations.

Comment: The backtracking solution I described above is going to work well for 15 people and 15 numbers, but might be too slow if you increase the number of people or the number of numbers. If you do, a dynamic programming approach might be preferable.